# CMS pages are not displaying correctly

Tags: magento-1.7, php, cms

Suddenly yesterday when I navigated to my home page, the menu bar does not drop down subcategories, the cart is not dropping down nor the compare function. The slideshow has dissapeared also and the currency switcher. The product slider and images are not loading either. They are shown as a broken image and only the tile, review and price are shown along with add to compare and wishlist buttons.

All other categories and product pages with the above functionality are working but it's only cms pages and the home page.

The below are the errors in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Catalog is not defined www.xxxxxx.com/:2041

Uncaught ReferenceError: Catalog is not defined (index):2

I have restored the website from two restore points and have gave me the same issues?

As I said the site was fine just a day ago and suddenly these problems.

Can anyone point me to a workaround or possibly an indication why this has happened?

I have only been adding products and that is it, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

`<cms_index_index>
    <update handle="MAP_popup" />
 </cms_index_index>`

It should be added somewhere between layout and /layout.

Answer (score 1):

hi i think you added products with "Map" enabled. but on home page there is no msrp.js available so remove those products or add

```
<reference name=”head”> <action method=”addItem”> <type>skin_js</type> <name>js/msrp.js</name> <params/> </action> </reference>
```

in your local.xml